# If I find a word and then How can I get Full word?

Tags: python

For example in a file) I like pineapple.

so I search "apple"

```
open(root_dir, encoding='UTF8').read().find("apple")
```

I want to get "pineapple". I mean full word.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Split the file contents into a list of words. Then search the list for one that contains `apple`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

```py
import re
result = re.findall(r'\w*apple\w*', # apple, surrounded by zero or more word symbols
                     'I got a pineapple, I got a pen.', # input string
                     re.I # optional: make search case insensitive
                    )
```

```py
>>> result
['pineapple']
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert that particular string to a `list` using `split()`, iterate over the list and Do a string match using `in`.

```
lst = ['apple', 'pineapple', 'fruit', 'applephone']
for i in lst:
    if 'apple' in i:
        print(i)
```

```
apple
pineapple
applephone
```

Answer (score -1):

Regular expression is one of many programming choices you can use to solve this problem.

Let assume that we have 4 words: apple pineapple applepine pineapplepine.
If you use the following pattern of regEx:

/\w*apple\w*/g --
You can match the whole word that contain a word “apple” in
“apple” “pineapple”  “applepine” and “pineapplepine”

/\w*apple/g --
You can match the whole word that contain a word “apple” in
“apple” and “pineapple”

/apple\w*/g --
You can match the whole word that contain a word “apple” in
“apple” and “applepine”

/apple/g --
You can match the whole word that contain a word “apple” in
“apple” ONLY.

Comment: Did you notice that the OP is asking for a solution in Python and that regular expressions have already been mentioned in a previous answer?

Comment: "How can I solve this problem?" that the sentence on the post?
Did you know /\w*apple\w*/g can found "pineapple" and "applepine" right?
So?